# как исправить автоисправление в visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, code-style

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как исправить автоисправления в студии?

Comment: Пробелы для слабых. :Р

Answer (score 1):

Вот где это настраивается:

Tools -> Options, потом заходим в раздел `Text Editor -> C/C++ -> Code Style -> Formatting` и там уже надо поправить всё, что Вам не нравится в автоформатировании.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]